# Discord bot response is +1 each time slash command is used?

Tags: counter

I'm using ccommandbot to make a custom bot for my discord server. I have absolutely no coding experience. I want to use /spill to track how many times someone spills liquid on their desk. So each time /spill is used, the response should be "We spilled 2 times" and the number increases by one each time the command is used.

I've tried copy and pasting some basic code I found online but I don't know which words to change to what in order to get my desired result